# Invalid salt version error in BCrypt.Net library - WinForms/C# application with MySQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, exception, bcrypt

I am currently making a password manager, therefore I make a log-in form with username and password fields. I want to `bcrypt` the password. I store the salt and the hashed password in the database ([screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOYPy.png)). When the user enters their username and password what I do is:

1.Retrieve the salt from the DB and use the `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password.Text, sal)` method to hash the submitted password  with the salt from the database

2.Retrieve the original **hashed** password from the db table, and then use the method `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(submhash, passdb)` to check if the 2 passwords hashes match.

3.If they do match I open the main form of the program.

However the VS Studio throws an exception : **Invalid salt version** ( [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUMrK.png))

I would like to ask where is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", username.Text);
           // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pas", password.Text);
            cmd.CommandText = "select password from users where username = @usr";
            passdb = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            MySqlCommand ss = new MySqlCommand();
            ss.Connection = conn;
            ss.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uun", username.Text);
            ss.CommandText = "select salt from users where username  = @uun";
            sal= (string)ss.ExecuteScalar();
            submhash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password.Text, sal);
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unm", username.Text);
            if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(submhash, passdb))
            {
                frmMain fm = new frmMain();
                SesUser.username = username.Text;
                SesUser.password = password.Text;
                this.Hide();
                fm.Show();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                i++;

            }

        }
```

Comment: BCrypt.Verify("my password", passwordHash); 
You're using the params in the wrong order and you shouldn't be specifying the salt.  BCrypt.HashPassword("my password");

Answer (score 3):

First you should wrap MySqlCommand inside a using statement, because DbCommand implements IDisposable.

Regarding your BCrypt issue.

You do not have to create a new hash and compare it to the saved hashed value. Because every time you do this you'll get a different hash.
You just have to verify a password against a saved hash with BCrypt.Net.

So the following should work

```
if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password.Text, passdb))
{
  // logged in
}
// not logged in
```

I'm expecting that `passdb` holds a bcrypt hash like the folowing:

```
$2a$12$VvDRKYKGt4Zd2Ux35LeG2OI.Vr5f.UuY2q7MrnHlJj4K5diifQV3e
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error when there was an invalid character in the 'prefix' of the encrypted string that bcrypt was supposed to hash/verify. Make sure your bcrypt function input string starts with a correct bcrypt version and salt length (ex: $2b$10) as shown [in this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description).

I would check the 'sal' string in your code to ensure it contains the proper hashing revision (starts with that $2b$xyz sequence)

Answer (score 3):

```
int salt = 12;
string passwordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(enteredpassword, salt);
bool correctPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(storedPassword, passwordHash);
```

I swapped **passwordHash** and **storedPassword** and **correctPassword** was true and program worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this issue too. In general with BCrypt you shouldn't have to handle the salt yourself and the library advises you to just let them generate it for you:

> Note: Although this library allows you to supply your own salt, it is
>   highly advisable that you allow the library to generate the salt for
>   you. These methods are supplied to maintain compatibility and for more
>   advanced cross-platform requirements that may necessitate their use.

After a lot of poking it turned out I was doing something very simple and very stupid - I'd passed the arguments in the wrong order. I've seen a few other questions on this topic floating around the internet, and for me digging into the library code itself was a rabbit hole - the problem was much more simple. Thus I'd recommend that if you are thinking about explicitly generating/handling a BCrypt salt yourself to solve a problem like this, look carefully for bugs in your implementation first.

Another key thing to note - if you do:

`dotnet add package BCrypt.Net`

Then at the time of writing I got BCrypt.Net 0.1.0, where the release I was expecting was 4.0.0. The correct package is called `BCrypt.Net-Next`:

`dotnet add package BCrypt.Net-Next --version 4.0.0`

Seemed to get the correct library.

The OP should consider disposing of IDisposables and selecting the salt and password in a single query since they're both in the same table to prevent extra roundtrips to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the string data at the funcTion Verify.

I had this erroR and my solution was:

with error:

```
if (Query == null || !BC.Verify(password (from DB), value.Password (from json))) {
```

without error OK:

```
if (Query == null || !BC.Verify(value.Password (from json), password (from DB)))
            {

                result = new
                {
                    Error = $"Account not found (Email or Username), please verify",
                    DataSended = value,
                };
            }
```